# Very slow connection to Snowflake from Databricks

Tags: performance, connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, sparklyr

I am trying to connect to Snowflake using R in databricks, my connection works and I can make queries and retrieve data successfully, however my problem is that it can take more than 25 minutes to simply connect, but once connected all my queries are quick thereafter.
I am using the sparklyr function 'spark_read_source', which looks like this:

```
query<- spark_read_source(
  sc = sc,
  name = "query_tbl",
  memory = FALSE,
  overwrite = TRUE,
  source = "snowflake",
  options = append(sf_options, client_Q)
)
```

where '*sf_options*' are a list of connection parameters which look similar to this;

```
 sf_options <- list(
  sfUrl = "https://<my_account>.snowflakecomputing.com",
  sfUser = "<my_user>",
  sfPassword = "<my_pass>",
  sfDatabase = "<my_database>",
  sfSchema = "<my_schema>",
  sfWarehouse = "<my_warehouse>",
  sfRole = "<my_role>"
)
```

and my query is a string appended to the '*options*' arguement e.g.
`client_Q <- 'SELECT * FROM <my_database>.<my_schema>.<my_table>'`
I can't understand why it is taking so long, if I run the same query from RStudio using a local spark instance and '*dbGetQuery*', it is instant.
Is spark_read_source the problem? Is it an issue between Snowflake and Databricks? Or something else? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more specifics? What cloud are you in? Any specifics for the network setup?

Comment: Sorry @FelipeHoffa for the delay in getting back to you I was away for a short while. The query is run inside a Databricks notebook which is then run through a cluster of EC2 instances. The issue however seems to have sorted itself out, thanks.